# Dynamic button column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This seems simple but it's becoming a source of great frustration for me. I'm creating a DataGridView and setting its DataSource to a list of an object which contains two properties... an int and a button. The first column works fine but the second is blank. After an SO search I realized my problem may be that my button column needed to be set as a DataGridViewButtonColumn, only when I try and set it as such it creates a new, third, button column.

How do I associate my auto-generated column as a DataGridViewButtonColumn? Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
List<EditGrid> items = new List<EditGrid>();

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    EditGrid eg = new EditGrid();

    eg.number = number;
    eg.edit = new Button() { Text = "Edit", Name = "Edit" };

    items.Add(eg);
}

DataGridView d = new DataGridView
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    AutoGenerateColumns = true,
    DataSource = items
};

Controls.Add(d);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use some custom `CellPainting` and don't set the `Text` of `DataGridViewButtonColumn` to anything (this is by default an empty string). Like this:

```
private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex > -1&&e.RowIndex > -1&&dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn)
        {                
            if (e.Value == null) return;
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
            //prepare format for drawing string yourself.
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            e.Graphics.DrawString(((Button)e.Value).Text, dataGridView.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, sf);                
        }
}
```

In your case replace `dataGridView` with `d`, looks like that you create your DataGridView using code, if so, you have to register the `CellPainting` event handler yourself like this:

```
d.CellPainting += dataGridView_CellPainting;
```

## UPDATE

to make your DataGridView have a DataGridViewButtonColumn first (without adding at design time), you have to add this code before setting your DataGridView's DataSource:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
col.HeaderText = "Your header";
col.Name = "button";
col.DataPropertyName = "Your DataSource Data member";//This is very important to match the corresponding Property or DataMember name of your DataSource.
col.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;//I suggest this because it looks more elegant.
d.Columns.Add(col);         
//----
d.DataSource = ...
```

I found that setting the `DisplayIndex` for your Button column doesn't work, instead, you may want to set its `DisplayIndex` after the `d.DataSource=...`, and it works:

```
d.DataSource = ...   ;
d.Columns["button"].DisplayIndex = ...;
```

Comment: Nice thank you. This will work for the text if I get it set as a button column first. Trying to combine this with the first answer...

Comment: @awhitehouse104 please see my update. ask anything more if you need.

Comment: Perfect thank you. Works now. The DataPropertyName is what I was missing as far as setting it as a button column.

Comment: @awhitehouse104 please see my update with much cleaner code (without using `DataBoundItem`, I thought the `e.Value` is pre-formatted by design but it is exactly the underlying `Button`. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    buttonCol.Name = "ButtonColumnName";
    buttonCol.HeaderText = "Header";
    buttonCol.Text = "Button Text";

    dataGridView.Columns.Add(buttonCol);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewButtonCell button = (row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"] as DataGridViewButtonCell);        
}
```

Comment: This just sets `Text` for all the Buttons in the `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. The OP seems to want to bind different `Text`s (which are taken from the DataSource) to the Button column.

Comment: @KingKing, Muhammad Hisham - I'm looking into this but yes I would like to do this via the DataSource... I do think I can make this work just not as cleanly as I would have hoped for